# Raspberry Pi not giving HDMI output with OS on SD card

Tags: raspberry-pi, operating-system, monitor, sd-card

I have a Raspberry Pi 4 Model B. When I boot it without an SD card (or when there is no OS installed on the SD card) it shows me this screen:
[image: screen on boot]

But when I install the Raspberry Pi OS using the Imager, it only says that there was no HDMI signal.
I tried removing all partitions from the SD card, formatting the second partition to FAT, reinstalling the OS, configuring the config.txt with hdmi_mode, hdmi_force_hotplug, etc.
I researched for a long time but couldn't find anymore solutions on this.

Edit: I'm using a Dell U2713H and the MicroHDMI-HDMI cable that came along with the Raspberry Pi plugged into HDMI0 Port.

Comment: By default, it should boot into the gui via hdmi without any manual changes. You therefore need to give more info. What monitor, cable, any adaptors, what is plugged into it, etc.